# Google Survey Help

Tags: google-forms

How do I share a google forms (survey) in a computer lab for several students to rotate through to complete without getting the error message that one has already completed the survey?

Answer (score 2):

Is the form configured to be limited to a single response?

Instructions to unset this (modified from google's online help) are:

> **New Google Forms (No "File" menu at top)**
>
> - Open the form.
> - At the top, click the Settings icon .
> - Un-check the box next to **Can only submit 1 response**.
>
> **Old Google Forms ("File" menu visible at top)**
>
> - Open the form.
> - In the "Form settings" section at the top, un-check the box next to **Limit to one response per user**.